# Elasticsearch Nest - Searching on Dynamic Data

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have an index being automapped from a fairly simple model.

The only complexity is a list of dynamic values where the users can create their own data. Each value has a Title (what the data is) and a Value. For example, 2 items in the array might be:

### Item 1

- Title - First Name
- Value - John

### Item 2

- Title - Surname
- Value - Thomas

There could be many of these and we don't know what they'll be. They can be added by users in the CMS.

My classes look something like this:

```
public class SearchRequest
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }

    public List<DynamicTextValue> DynamicTextValues { get; set; }
}

public class DynamicTextValue
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The generic mapping looks like this:

```
"documentId": {
    "type": "integer"
},
"documentName": {
    "type": "text"
},
"dynamicTextValues": {
    "properties": {
        "value": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have dynamicNumericValues and dynamicDateValues with a similar concept.

The problem is when I want to search on one of the dynamic types. Let's say I search for surname "Thomas". I add 2 "must" searches:

- Title = Surname
- Value = Thomas

Or

- q=dynamicTextValues.title:Surname AND dynamicTextValues.value:Thomas

This won't work because the two fields are independent of each other. It will actually return records where any Value is Thomas (e.g. Thomas is also a First Name) as long as it contains a title with Surname somewhere in the same record. I need it to return only where Value is Thomas on the same list item that the Title is Surname.

Is there any way this can be done? Or is there a better way to structure my data to achieve these results? I considered (as a hack) concatenating the Title and Value and searching for "Surname Thomas" but this won't solve the problem for numeric and date fields.

Answer (score 1):

`DynamicTextValue` needs to be mapped as a [`nested` data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) for this to work. `nested` data types are internally mapped as separate documents, maintaining the relationship between the properties, `title` and `value` in this case.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! You're a star, mate.